# PHP serialize protected class variables with wrong character count?

Tags: php, object-serialization

I am dealing with a strange problem in PHP 5.2.6, serializing objects.

Apparently, PHP stores protected variables members with an asterix ahead of its name. That is normal and correct, however, look at the following example:

```
O:18:"object__songChords":1:{s:9:"*chords"}
```

***chords** does not contain 9 characters, but 7 (with the asterix).

Naturally, i assumed that there is some misunderstanding on my side, and that PHP just counts the quotes, but when i compare this to other strings stored, i find that this is not the case.

Bottomline is that PHP fails to unserialize these objects, although the classes have not changed.

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 43 of 867 bytes in ...
```

Can anyone offer some insight on this?

**EDIT (providing the class)**

```
class object__songChords {
  protected $chords;
  protected $lyrics;
}
```

Please note that i stripped the above serialization example for the sake of simplicity – the actual serialization string of course contains both properties.

Comment: can you provide the class? and the data as an example php file?

Comment: Yes, i just edited the question

Comment: Are you sure that this is the full serialized string?

Comment: Please see my comment at the end of my question. At any rate, i could provide the full string, but contains chord definitions and is hard to read. The issue at hand is that PHP counts 9 characters for *chords ..

Comment: I have created a example, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/21b6ad06b31a6fc9ac4ae6512cc973bd34d9583a

Comment: I think if you were to look at the output from serializing the string, you may notice there's some invisible characters (`\000`) around the asterisk, which is why you think the count is off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The count is not off, there are two `\0` null characters separating the `*`, one on each side:

```
$o = new object__songChords;
echo addslashes(serialize($o));
```

Yields:

```
O:18:\"object__songChords\":2:{s:9:\"\0*\0chords\";N;s:9:\"\0*\0lyrics\";N;}
```